# Is it OK to fetch data in App.js? (to conditionally render views)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, react-apollo

I would like to know more about the standards of setting upp a React app, **the do's and don'ts**.

To conditionally allow a user to visit a page or not, could I for example fetch data in App.js (or even index.js?) to then conditionally render the Router links?

To me it sounds bad to do fetching in App.js but that might not matter at all. I guess the idea is that it could slow down the app or make the code less readable.

Any thoughts on this? Or any place I can read more about this.

Code example might help:

```
//App.js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useQuery, gql } from '@apollo/client';

import NavBar from './components/NavBar';
import Start from './views/Start';
import Approvals from './views/Approvals';

const GET_USERINFO = gql`
  query {
    userRole {
      canApproveReports
    }
  }
`;

function App() {
  const { data } = useQuery(GET_USERINFO);

  return (
    <Router>
      <NavBar />
      <Route exact path="/" component={start} />
      
                                             // THE GOOD STUFF
      {data?.userRole.CanApproveReports && (
        <Route exact path="/approvals" component={approvals} />
      )}

    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: You can fetch data in App.js thats absolutly fine,  use `useQuery` in a useEffect hook with empty deps array `[]`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I've looked into this async fetching in React and stumbled upon problems with my queries. I didn't know I could useQuery **inside** useEffect? that possibly solves a lot of my problems. but then the `data` from useQuery has to be set as a state variable?

Comment: I am sorry, you can use `useQuery` as you are using. I got confused with `useLazyQuery` which we normally use inside a useEffect hook or during a button click